# Customizing Sharepoint 2013 List Header

Tags: sharepoint

My company just converted to SP 2013 and I am now trying to create a new list.  I have been trying to customize my header to have the following attribute:

Wrapped Text
Font Color Blue
Text Allignment - Center
Vertical alignment - bottom

I have found a script that allowed me to wrap the headers on all of the columns and I tried adding to it the color and text allignment.  What I keep running into is that it is only updating the color and allignment on my one header that is not filterable.  I have tried to look up what each of the .ms items mean because I am assuming that is my issue, but I can not seem to find the answer to that question.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<style>
    .ms-vh, .ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2-nograd, .ms-vh2, .ms-vb{
        white-space: normal; 
        color:#0000ff;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align:text-bottom;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done some test and this is the css file

```
---------- Table Rows ----------*/
    ms-vh-div,ms-vh2-nofilter,ms-vh-div{
        background: #2E4C70;
    }
/* Set background for every row */
    .ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr {
        background: white;
    }

 Set border for every row */
    .ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr td{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #AFAFAF !important; /* !important needed over override SharePoint inline style */
    }

 Set background for every alternating row */
    .ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr.ms-alternating {
        background: #E2E3E5;
    } Table Header Row 
 Remove background set in SharePoints general data table style */
    .ms-listviewtable tr.ms-viewheadertr {
        background: transparent;
         width:100%;
    }

.ms-viewheadertr,
    .ms-listviewtable {

width:100%;
}tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2-nograd {   color:white;}

 Modify background color */
 tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2-nograd,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon, /* Input box and attachment icon */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh, /* Text */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2 ,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr >th.ms-vh2-nofilter,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr >th.ms-vh-div/* Text */ {
        background: #2E4C70;
    }
.ms-viewheadertr {

width:100%;
}


 Modify background color on hover */
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh:hover,
    tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2:hover {
                background-color: #273C51;
                border-color: #273C51;
        }

 Modify font color */
    .ms-viewheadertr a,
    .ms-viewheadertr div {
        color: grey;
    }

 Modify font color on hover */
    .ms-viewheadertr a:hover,
    .ms-viewheadertr div:hover {
        color: blue;
    }
```

more details here[sharepoint experience](http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2012/05/simple-styles-sharepoint-list/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a Script Editor web part, and insert this:

```
/*Choose your background colour*/
.ms-viewheadertr{
background:#00426A;
}

/*Choose font style*/
.ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2, a.ms-headerSortTitleLink {
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
font-size:1.05em;
}

</style>
```

With thanks to Nate Chamberlain:
https://natechamberlain.com/2018/07/20/customize-styles-formatting-of-sharepoint-list-column-header-rows/

Answer (score 0):

The formatting does not apply to multiple line of text field.

Comment: This should be a comment